# python unit test test case for while loop with date constraint

Tags: mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to write a unit test for the scenario below. I'm unable to figure out how to mock the scenario to capture `clientdata.tcperror` raised in the while loop.

```py
def allocate(self, clientname, testtime):
    client = clientdata.ClientInformation(clientdata.TO_Test)
    endtime = datetime + testtime
    while datetime.now < endtime:
        try:
            output = client.getClientInfo(name, min=testtime)
            print("client found resp")
            if output is None:
                continue
            else:
                 return
         except clientdata.tcperror as e:
              time.sleep(10)
    raise ClientNotFoundError("Attempt abort")
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? That `time.sleep` is called after the exception?

Comment: Above script will continue till end time if exception is seen. How do I iterate through while loop till the end time of loop to exit and get ClientNotFoundError ? in py unit testing. The test case I wrote doesn’t loop though till end time , it just runs once and fails. </Br>